# How can I calculate total points of a user on his answers upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation

My employer want to calculate the total points of a user on his answers only. He don't believe in the reputation earned through questions!

If technically impossible, just the sum of upvotes and best answer points sum of his answer. (without edit, chosen best)